# How do you add gas limit to your cryptocurrency?

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain

How do you add gas limit to your cryptocurrency?

Comment: I recommend you start with reading [Intro to Ethereum](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/intro-to-ethereum/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add gas limit to your function in solidity on your ERC-20 or ERC-721 smart contract,  and not "on crypto currency " to be precise .
So You just need to specify the gas limit for the function you want on your smart contract :for example on function Withdraw() .

If you use metamask and want specifi gas limit you need to go in advance and you will see the gas limit where you can change it when you send or do some stuff with your  crypto .